# Are cookie based redirects possilbe on Netlify?

Tags: server, firebase-authentication, netlify

I have a web app that uses firebase for auth.  Once a user signs up/logs in there is always a certain cookie present.

I would like to, based on the presence of that cookie, redirect the user from the root path to a sub path i.e. `site.com`=>`site.com/app` whenever they visit the site.

I'm using Netlify to host my site and I've read through [their documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-netlify-configuration-file)
but I can't figure out anyway to do this.  It appears as though the only "conditions" that can be used for a redirect are langauge & role, but nothing about cookies.

Maybe this is possible using [JWT Roles](https://docs.netlify.com/visitor-access/role-based-access-control/#create-users-and-set-roles)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible today, but you can keep an eye on this thread: https://community.netlify.com/t/expanding-functionality-of-redirects/988/36?u=goleary